# How to underline misspelled words in TextBox like Microsoft Word ?

Tags: c#, textbox

I have a TextBox with Text, and take every word and underline it if it is misspelled. 
How can I underline wrong words ?

Thanks

Comment: WinForms or WPF? If you're working with WPF, Harsh Mauryas solution will do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the below link. There is a class for what what you want to achieve, if you're working in **WPF**: [**SpellCheck Class**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.spellcheck%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: WinForms. I forgot to write this, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Windows Forms then you have to build your own library of Grammar and spellings then try to use some comparer.

For Web applications you can use some online solution to check grammar and spellings then apply styles through CSS.  Here is a tool for ASP.NET Spell Check [ASPNetSpell](http://www.aspnetspell.com/)